# Probability of seeing a headlight getting switched on

Tags: probability

I'm new here and I'm not sure if the is the correct place to post this problem that's been bothering me.

From my apartment, I can see a stretch of highway with fairly heavy traffic. During the day, I can see all cars have their headlights off. As it gets dark, I start to see some cars with their headlights on. Eventually all of them have their lights on.

However, in many months, I am YET to see a car switching on a headlight during that stretch of highway. Hence the problem:

Given the following variables, how can I calculate the probability of seeing at least one car switch on its headlight during a specific period on a specific stretch of highway.

Let us assume that all cars will *randomly* switch on their headlights any time between 6 and 7 pm. And lets assume I can only see one side of the highway.

```
d = 2000 meters (stretch of highway)
v = 100 kmph (speed of each car, assumed constant throughout)
f = 4 (The number of cars entering the highway each second)
```

If I start watching the highway at 6pm (when all headlights are off) and stop and 7pm (when all headlights are on), what is the probability that I will see at least one car switch on its headlight on that stretch of the highway?

Is there sufficient data to answer the question?

Comment: Your traffic volume seems off.  That's $4\times 60\times 60=14400$ cars per hour that you observe.  Seems high.

Comment: It's a six lane highway in India. I assure you it's quite normal. Anyway, you can use 2 if you like.

Comment: Even with $2$, you'd expect to see well over $100$, under your assumptions.  My guess, for what it's worth, is that your "randomness" assumption is off.  I'll bet a lot of people leaving work just turn their lights on when they start their car.

Comment: I quite agree. I was actually interested in the mathematical formula to calculate this.

Comment: Well, (sticking with your assumptions, including the number $4$), the probability that a single car turns on its lights within the window is $p=\frac 1{50}$.  Thus the odds that none of the $14400$ do is $(1-\frac 1{50})^{14400}\sim 4.5\times 10^{-127}$.  And that's just one day.

Answer (score 1):

You observe each car for $\frac 2{100}=\frac1{50}$ hours, so with $4$ cars entering per second during an observation length of $3600$ seconds, you observe $\frac{4\cdot 3600}{50} =288$ "car-hours" and hence should *expect* to observe $288$ cars switching on their lights while you watch. (I must admit though that $14400$ cars passing during an hour seems to be quite a lot).

Comment: You should visit India sometime to see the traffic! Anyway, 288 seems like a very high number considering I haven't seen any yet. A majority of the cars would switch on their lights before they hit the stretch.